# gradlew assembleDebug failing when building apk with buildozer

Tags: android, python, kivy, gradlew, buildozer

I am trying to build a signed apk using buildozer on a virtual machine which is running on windows 10 but I am getting this error:

```
[INFO]:    Selecting java build tool:
[INFO]:    Detected highest available build tools version to be 28.0.3
[INFO]:        Building with gradle, as gradle executable is present
[DEBUG]:   -> running gradlew assembleDebug
[DEBUG]:    > Configuring > 0/1 projects > root project > Resolving       dependen
[DEBUG]:    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * What went wrong:
[DEBUG]:    A problem occurred configuring root project 'myapp'.
[DEBUG]:    > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
[DEBUG]:       > Could not find common.jar (com.android.tools:common:25.3.1).
[DEBUG]:         Searched in the following locations:
[DEBUG]:             https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.3.1/common-25.3.1.jar
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * Try:
[DEBUG]:    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    BUILD FAILED
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    Total time: 33.436 secs
[DEBUG]:    
Exception in thread background thread for pid 10226:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2170, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1929, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 672, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: ./gradlew assembleDebug

  STDOUT:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'myapp'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find common.jar (com.android.tools:common:25.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.3.1/common-25.3.1.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 33.436 secs


  STDERR:


[INFO]:    STDOUT:
    > Configuring > 0/1 projects > root project > Resolving dependencies ':c    
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.    

* What went wrong:  
A problem occurred configuring root project 'myapp'.    
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.   
   > Could not find common.jar (com.android.tools:common:25.3.1).   
     Searched in the following locations:   
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.3.1/common-25.3.1.jar  

* Try:  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.  

BUILD FAILED    

Total time: 33.436 secs 

[INFO]:    STDERR:

[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /home/kivy/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp && ./gradlew assembleDebug

[WARNING]: ERROR: ./gradlew failed!
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python2.7 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name myapp --name 'My Application' --version 0.1 --package org.test.myapp --android_api 19 --minsdk 19 --private /home/kivy/helloworld/.buildozer/android/app --icon /home/kivy/helloworld/./data/icon.png --orientation landscape --copy-libs --local-recipes /home/kivy/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/recipes --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir="/home/kivy/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/build"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I checked the address displayed in the error log [1](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/) and common-25.3.1.jar does not seems to exist there.

Here is my main.py:

```
__version__ = "0.1"
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        f = FloatLayout()
        s = Scatter()
        l = Label(text="Hello!",
                  font_size=150)

        f.add_widget(s)
        s.add_widget(l)
        return f

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        TutorialApp().run()
```

and here is my buildozer.spec:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = My Application

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy,python2

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = landscape

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
android.minapi = 19

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

p4a.local_recipes = %(source.dir)s/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/recipes
# (list) python-for-android whitelist
#android.p4a_whitelist =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

I need help getting around this issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need this :

```
#(list) Gradle dependencies to add

#android.gradle_dependencies =
```

because your buildozer.spec doesn't exist